# How to authenticate non domain computer using System.DirectoryServices using credentials

Tags: c#, active-directory

When i use following code to connect to domain controller from domain member computer with domain admin account it works.But i cannot make connection with same credentials from non domain computer.

```
DirectoryContext domainContext = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, "mydomain.com", username_to_connect,password_to_connect);

var domain =System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetDomain(domainContext);
```

i connect like above and get some information like this

```
string forestlevel = domain.Forest.ForestMode.ToString();
```

but i cannot do same when im connecting from non domain computer.

i get following error

> {"Current security context is not associated with an Active Directory
>   domain or forest."}

is it possible to connect domain controller this way from non domain computer ?